# How to combine Fuzzy C-means clustering and Support vector regression for building a hybrid model FCM-SVR in R?

Tags: fuzzy-c-means-clustering

I have read one article and found that they used the Fuzzy C-means clustering algorithm and support vector regression for building the FCM-SVR predictive model.
I see they split the data into 3 clusters by FCM. Then, each cluster builds an SVR model. Finally, they get a FCM-SVR hybrid model.
However, I do not understand how can they build SVR models from clusters? How can they build the FCM-SVR hybrid model?
P/s: I am using R programming language.

Comment: Please give me an answer

Comment: ................

Comment: Does anyone know about this problem? Please explain for helping me